# How to read nested JSON structure?

Tags: json, r, plyr, rbind

I have some JSON that looks like this:

```
"total_rows":141,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"1","key":"a","value":{"SP$Sale_Price":"240000","CONTRACTDATE$Contract_Date":"2006-10-26T05:00:00"}},
{"id":"2","key":"b","value":{"SP$Sale_Price":"2000000","CONTRACTDATE$Contract_Date":"2006-08-22T05:00:00"}},
{"id":"3","key":"c","value":{"SP$Sale_Price":"780000","CONTRACTDATE$Contract_Date":"2007-01-18T06:00:00"}},
...
```

In R, what would be the easiest way to produce a scatter-plot of `SP$Sale_Price` versus `CONTRACTDATE$Contract_Date`?

I got this far:

```
install.packages("rjson")
library("rjson")
json_file <- "http://localhost:5984/testdb/_design/sold/_view/sold?limit=100"
json_data <- fromJSON(file=json_file)
install.packages("plyr")
library(plyr)
asFrame <- do.call("rbind.fill", lapply(json_data, as.data.frame))
```

but now I'm stuck...

```
> plot(CONTRACTDATE$Contract_Date, SP$Sale_Price)
Error in plot(CONTRACTDATE$Contract_Date, SP$Sale_Price) : 
  object 'CONTRACTDATE' not found
```

How to make this work?

Comment: errors don't get much clearer than `object 'CONTRACTDATE' not found`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have the following JSON-file:

```
txt <- '{"total_rows":141,"offset":0,"rows":[
  {"id":"1","key":"a","value":{"SP$Sale_Price":"240000","CONTRACTDATE$Contract_Date":"2006-10-26T05:00:00"}},
  {"id":"2","key":"b","value":{"SP$Sale_Price":"2000000","CONTRACTDATE$Contract_Date":"2006-08-22T05:00:00"}},
  {"id":"3","key":"c","value":{"SP$Sale_Price":"780000","CONTRACTDATE$Contract_Date":"2007-01-18T06:00:00"}}]}'
```

Then you can read it as follows with the `jsonlite` package:

```
library(jsonlite)
json_data <- fromJSON(txt, flatten = TRUE)

# get the needed dataframe
dat <- json_data$rows
# set convenient names for the columns
# this step is optional, it just gives you nicer columnnames
names(dat) <- c("id","key","sale_price","contract_date")
# convert the 'contract_date' column to a datetime format
dat$contract_date <- strptime(dat$contract_date, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", tz="GMT")
```

Now you can plot:

```
plot(dat$contract_date, dat$sale_price)
```

Which gives:

[image]

---

If you choose not to flatten the JSON, you can do:

```
json_data <- fromJSON(txt)

dat <- json_data$rows$value

sp <- strtoi(dat$`SP$Sale_Price`)
cd <- strptime(dat$`CONTRACTDATE$Contract_Date`, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", tz="GMT")
plot(cd,sp)
```

Which gives the same plot:

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you! I'm a little disappointed that the flattening discards the field names. I have 700 attributes in my real json data. Is there any way to preserve the attribute names?

Comment: @AlexR The flattening doesn't discard the fieldnames. Look at the structure of `json_data`. You will see that `value.` is added in front of the field names. The step about setting the names of `dat` is not necessary and thus optional. See the update.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that doesn't discard the field names:

```
install.packages("jsonlite")
install.packages("curl")
json <- fromJSON(json_file)
r <- json$rows
```

At this point `r` looks like this:

```
> class(r)
[1] "data.frame"
> colnames(r)
[1] "id"    "key"   "value"
```

After some more Googling and trial-and-error I landed on this:

```
f <- r$value
sp <- strtoi(f[["SP$Sale_Price"]])
cd <- strptime(f[["CONTRACTDATE$Contract_Date"]], format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", tz="GMT")
plot(cd,sp)
```

And the result on my full data-set...

[image]